# iphone - stopping a method that is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path] method. is there anyway of stopping it midway? like terminating the method.

Reason for doing is because im running an apache http server on one pc and if the server is not running, the app will 'hang' if this method is called. so i want to to something like terminating the method after a certain amount of seconds , 5s maybe.  and display an alert message.

Comment: Are you doing all the hard socket work yourself with the Berkeley Sockets API? If so, you may use the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option to set a timeout to your `recv`/`recvfrom` calls. On timeout, they'll return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Comment: hmm nope im not doing any socket work .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have two suggestions... one, if you possibly can, use NSMutableURLRequest with NSURLConnection to retrieve the data; which gives you much better control over things like timeout.

```
NSError * error;
NSURLResponse * response;

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest
     requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]
     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
     timeoutInterval:60.0];

// Not sure if you need this, but I frequently do POSTs as well, so whatever:
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSData * responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString * xml = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

(NB: You'll have to check the error response, I just omitted it for clarity)

Also, ideally (since in my example I use the synchronous method) this should be run on a background thread... but I found it much easier to run this on the background thread manually using "performSelectorInBackground:" and use the synchronous methods, than I did using the async methods. Keep in mind, you'll have to create your own auto release pool if you do that... but that's two lines, and it's super easy.

Short of that, it IS possible to terminate the method... you'd have to run it on a different thread, and kill the thread if it took too long... but really, the NSMutableURLRequest isn't so bad, and it already gives you the timeout options you're looking for.

The thread programming guide at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2 talks about killing threads... and tells you (indirectly) how to do it... but if you simply kill the thread, you are almost guaranteed to leak *something*.

Comment: hmm could u give an answer on how to kill the method? on a different thread.

Comment: @kenneth: simple; Scroll to the bottom of the linked document (I think their point about memory management should be very carefully considered. If you truly kill the thread, you're bound to have memory issues) http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2

Comment: hmm i think im going to stick with the request method :) . one question though, how do you set the request result to a data object? i mean ur last line, responseData(I presume its a data object)

Comment: @kenneth: WHOOPS! That's what I get for copy-paste. I updated the post.

Comment: You can use a shorter timeout interval instead of trying to cancel the request.

Comment: @kenneth: no problem... it was sorta weird for me the first time, so I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you could try installing a signal handler with [`sigaction`](http://wwwcgi.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/man/2/sigaction) to handle `SIGALRM` and use the [`alarm`](http://wwwcgi.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/man/2/alarm) function. There is, however, probably a better solution using the Cocoa framework. I'll leave this here, but it's probably not the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

A method is just a C(++) function, so there really no way to stop it.

Comment: That's not true. While most aren't clean, there are several ways to stop the execution of a function.